# Can't dismiss keyboard in Interface Builder because view controller won't show doneEditing:

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, modalviewcontroller

Have an AddEntryViewController (modal segue), and want to dismiss the keyboard by control-clicking from the textField to the View Controller.

Trouble is, when I get to the ViewController, instead of showing doneEditing: in the HUD, it only shows different segue selections.

Why is it doing this, and how do I get it to show the right information in the HUD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a UITextField in iOS, it does not call an action called doneEditing.

In fact it doesn't send any actions and it can't trigger a segue. Therefore, Interface Builder assumes you'd like to create a segue from the current view controller to another.

You must dismiss the text field's keyboard by implementing the textfieldShouldReturn delegate method. In it you can ask the text field to resign its first responder status which will make the keyboard go away. This screencast explains more: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-from-a-uitextfield-in-ios/

If you only want to dismiss the keyboard as soon as the view is dismissed, implement it in viewWillDisappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.yourTextfield resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```